# Nuxt environment variables in nuxt.config.ts

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

nuxt.config.ts:

```
env: {
  cmsUrl: process.env.CMS_URL || 'http://localhost:1337'
}
```

I'm setting `CMS_URL` as system variable on a production/staging mode, otherwise it would use a localhost in a dev mode.

However if i reuse this env variable inside nuxt.config.ts:

```
axios: {
  baseURL: process.env.cmsUrl
}
```

My NUXT app won't even start, saying ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80, i assume thats because env variable is not working.

Comment: Got the same issue, but I can't pass env from cloud run to my nuxt app which cause undefined, i think that nuxt-ts is not running the same behaviour as nuxt in JS, for now I've to pass env during run 'nuxt-ts build' to make it works. It not a nice idea when you have to change something. Which I've to rebuild it every time

Comment: This might related to this issue [https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5100](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5100)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Environment Variables in nuxt.config.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973709/using-environment-variables-in-nuxt-config-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the stage, where i was applying environment variables, i was applying them in a docker-compose file, with `npm run start` command, and i built image one stage before with `npm run build`, that's why my env variables wasn't picked at all.