# Using Environment Variables in nuxt.config.js

Tags: node.js, axios, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt & Axios but having trouble using environment variables when **building** the application from my **local machine**.

I have installed the @nuxtjs/dotenv module in an attempt to fix this issue but still having problems.

Note: The environment variables work fine when building the app within my hosting providers environment. It is only building from my local machine that gives me trouble. My IDE is VS Code.

Here is my axios setup inside nuxt.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
  ...
}
```

My .env file has the following:

```
BASE_URL="https://some.api.com"
```

The .env variables are not being recognized when building the app:

```
nuxt build
```

Instead, it just sets the axios base url to the same host:port that the server runs on by default. Ex: localhost:4000

I found the following documentation from @nuxtjs/dotenv module: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module#using-env-file-in-nuxtconfigjs. This instructs you to add the following to the top of nuxt.config.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

This works for building locally; my variables from .env are recognized! However, because dotenv is a dev dependency, this causes the build to crash when deployed to my hosting provider because the module isn't recognized.

I know that I can define the environment variables directly in the build command as follows but **I would prefer NOT to do so**:

```
NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL=some.api.com nuxt build
```

Is there an easy way to get environment variables to work locally inside of nuxt.config.js during the build process that also works well when deploying to production??

Thank you!

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Nope, not yet. Sorry

Comment: I found a working solution after asking this. I added it below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Updated 2020-09-26

As of 2.13.0 I have removed @nuxtjs/dotenv. My nuxt.config.js now simply reads as below with the dotenv imports removed. I made no other code changes and the rest functions exactly the same for me.

```
env: {
  DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST
},
```

My .env contains the following.

```
DB_HOST=http://localhost:5001/
```

### Original answer

I installed the following as a dev dependency; @nuxtjs/dotenv. Then I added the following to my nuxt.config.js. I found this import statement [in an article](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/20/create-a-blog-with-contentful-and-nuxt/) and tried it. Thankfully it worked for me.

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

env: {
  DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST
},
```

I created a file called .env with the following content

```
DB_HOST=http://localhost:5001/
```

Comment: I did the same exact thing yesterday and it didn't work.
I did it today and now it works.
Well. Thank you I guess.

Not sure if it's crucial, but I also have following code in my `nuxt.config.js`:

  `buildModules: [ '@nuxtjs/dotenv' ]`
The last one is `@nuxtjs/dotenv`. My version is ^2.15, but it does work and i dont wanna touch it

Answer (score 10):

In nuxt version v2.13.0, support for `Runtime Config` was added. This adds proper support to read environment variables at runtime. Previously they could be read but were compiled into the application.

The standard documentation is pretty good: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime-config/ .
There is also a great blog post on how to migrate. You remove the use of `@nuxtjs/dotenv`.

https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/

For example, in your nuxt.config.js, you define.

```
  // Public env variables that are exposed on the frontend.
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    someAccessKeyId: process.env.SOME_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  },
  // Private env variables that are not be exposed on the frontend.
  privateRuntimeConfig: {},
```

Then in your vue code, you access it via.

```
const { someAccessKeyId } = this.$config
```

Comment: How are you supposed to use RuntimeConfig inside of the nuxt.config.js file?

Comment: Those are just top level keys in `nuxt.config.js`.  As I mentioned, then you can just refer to them in code as I described using `this.$config`.

Comment: I don't think you understand @Derek, How do I want to access `someAccessKeyId` in another part of the `nuxt.config.js` file

Comment: Oh. I haven't tried that. I guess you can always just go back and use the `process.env` directly if you need access to an env variable.

Comment: @Derek I am having the same issue, those values are just empty if you refer to them as process.env in for example your modules object below

Comment: How can we access variables from privateRuntimeConfig in a plugin ?

Comment: @derek this is spot on. I removed @nuxtjs/dotenv and then modified my nuxt.config.js to removing `import dotenv from "dotenv";` and `dotenv.config();` while leaving `env: {   DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST },` and everything else works exactly the same.

Comment: did you ever get a solution @AndreOdendaal?

Comment: I cannot remember unfortunately @richardwhatever

Comment: I'm no longer actively working with nuxt so it's been a while. If you need to access `someAccessKeyId` in some other place in `nuxt.config.js` you probably can't directly. You should be able to reference `process.env.SOME_ACCESS_KEY_ID` though.

Comment: this problem was driving me crazy: I have the .env file in the root directory but with process.env.XXX I got always "undefined". I finally solved using your solution, thank you!

Comment: @StephenVernyi `How are you supposed to use RuntimeConfig inside of the nuxt.config.js file?`

 you don't, just use process.env