# Using .env (dotenv) files in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js, dotenv

How to use `dotenv` / `.env` files in `Nuxt.js`?

My approach, which is the following one, doesn't work.

I have two different env files with different constants inside: `BASE_URL=localhost:1337` and `BASE_URL=https://my-app.heroku.com"`. The files path / names are:

```
root_project/.env
root_project/.env.production
```

In `nuxt.config.js` I have tried both runtime config and also env:

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
},

env: {
  BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
},
```

Then inside e.g. `default/index.vue` or `pages/index.vue` I verify it with:

```js
created() {
  console.log('env', process.env.NODE_ENV)
  console.log('baseUrl', this.$config.BASE_URL)
}
```

Build (`npm run build`) and start (`NODE_ENV=production npm run start`) shows:

```
env production 
baseUrl localhost:1337
```

**Why are the values from `.env.production` not read??**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Environment Variables in nuxt.config.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973709/using-environment-variables-in-nuxt-config-js)